# On android 5.0,if a textview has set lineSpacingExtra, and has only one line text, the textview doesn't show linespacing

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

It's different with other android version below 5.0！
Demo code:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="100dp"
    android:text="Hello World!"/>
```

On android 5.0, it shows:
[image]

Below android 5.0, it shows:
[image]

But if textview has more than two lines, they show the same! 
How can I do to make them show the same on different os version?
Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set a `paddingBottom` to the view over Lollipop like

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="100dp"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding"/>
```

and set `padding=0dp` in the `dimens` (values-v19) and set `padding=100dp` in the `dimens` (values-v21)